# Check whether a property of an object exists and only update another property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with objects that look like this:

```
    let arr = [
        { taxonomy: 'category', id: [ 10, 100 ] },
        { taxonomy: 'post_tag', id: [ 20 ] },
    ];
```

I want to be able to push a new object in the array that look like this:

```
    const object = {
        taxonomy: 'category',
        id: 30
    }
```

What i want is a check if an object in the array with the property value 'taxonomy' already exists, if it does i want to only add the id from the new object in to the existing object. I know how to check if the property already exists but i don't exactly know how to add the new id to the array.

So adding the above object would result in this array:

```
    [
        { taxonomy: 'category', id: [ 10, 100, 30 ] }, // 30 is added
        { taxonomy: 'post_tag', id: [ 20 ] },
    ];
```

if it doesn't exist yet it should be added.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: `if(arr[0].taxonomy)....`

Comment: Since your objects only have two properties which look like a key and a value, have you considered using an object instead of an array? `let obj = {category:[10,100],post_tag:[20]}` This would simplify searching for a matching taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the array and update or push a new object with `id` as array to the array.

```js
const
    array = [{ taxonomy: 'category', id: [ 10, 100 ] }, { taxonomy: 'post_tag', id: [ 20 ] }];
    object = { taxonomy: 'category', id: 30 },
    item = array.find(({ taxonomy }) => object.taxonomy === taxonomy);

if (item) {
    item.id.push(object.id);
} else {
    array.push(Object.assign({}, object, { id: [object.id] }));
}

console.log(array);

   // remove the last insert
   // find item with taxonomy and id
   item =  array.find(({ taxonomy, id }) => object.taxonomy === taxonomy && id.includes(object.id));

// remove from id by using the index
if (item) item.id.splice(item.id.indexOf(object.id), 1);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nina Scholz works great! Can you also tell me how i can check within the if statement if the item.id already exists in the array so i can remove it from the array?

Comment: in this case, you could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with the same callback and check if the value is unequal `-1` and splice the array with this index, if you have only one item, or filter the array and assign the filtered array to `array`.

Comment: thanks, i just can't seem to figure out how to do this.. i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @keviniooooooo, i added an example how to remove an existent `id`.

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz, i find it a bit confusing, should the example be added inside the first if statement? Some context: i put all of this code in to a function that's been triggered on a checkbox onChange event

Comment: thi first part is putting the `id` *in* the array, the last part *removes* the `id` from the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.find()` to locate an object with the same taxonomy in the array. If one exists, add the `id` to it. If not, push a clone of the object into the array (after converting the object's `id` to array):

```js
const addUpdate = obj => {
  const current = arr.find(o => obj.taxonomy === o.taxonomy);
  
  if(current) current.id.push(obj.id);
  else arr.push({
    ...obj,
    id: [obj.id]
  })
};

const arr = [
  { taxonomy: 'category', id: [ 10, 100 ] },
  { taxonomy: 'post_tag', id: [ 20 ] },
];

addUpdate({ taxonomy: 'category', id: 30 });

addUpdate({ taxonomy: 'other', id: 50 });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `forEach` for looping and pushing the new id.

```js
let arr = [{taxonomy: 'category',id: [10, 100]},{taxonomy: 'post_tag',id: [20]},],
    object = {taxonomy: 'category',id: 30};

arr.forEach(({taxonomy, id}) => {
  if (object.taxonomy === taxonomy) {
    id.push(object.id);
  }   
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `upsert()` function like below, you can accomplish this with a little bit of abstraction, so that it can be re-used for more than just this particular schema. `upsert()` contains some reasonable defaults for the functions, which would work fine if all the objects are dictionaries with primitive values

```js
function upsert (
  array, object, keyFn,
  updateFn = (target, object) => Object.assign(target, object),
  insertFn = object => object
) {
  const key = keyFn(object)
  const index = array.findIndex(
    value => keyFn(value) === key
  )

  if (index !== -1) updateFn(array[index], object)
  else array.push(insertFn(object))
}

let arr = [
  { taxonomy: 'category', id: [10, 100] },
  { taxonomy: 'post_tag', id: [20] }
]

const obj = { taxonomy: 'category', id: 30 }

upsert(
  arr, obj,
  o => o.taxonomy, // used to determine if existing object should be updated
  (t, o) => t.id.push(o.id), // operation for updating existing object
  ({ id, ...o }) => ({ ...o, id: [id] }) // return new object to insert
)

console.log(arr)
```